# Tourist guide for self-made holiday

Tags: guides, local-knowledge

I usually travel planning the vacation by myself.

During my holiday I notice a real difference between cities visited alone from cities visited with a local friend of mine.

How can I find an "informal" guide to help me to discover hidden stories/particular in the cities I want to visit? (not in a particular one)

I am looking for a service, so I anyone knows one can suggest it to me?

Comment: did you check out couch surfing ? Or AirBnB. Most providers will double up to be a guide to their town

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you are looking for?

Comment: I would like to know if exixst a way to find a local guide for my future long-stay weekend (2014: Stockholm and/or Bacelona and so on)

Answer (score 3):

I would say that [Geocaching](http://www.geocaching.com) would count as a prime resource. I have used this website for exactly this purpose in various cities. Geocaching is a game where locals hide something at very interesting locations for others to find. The game is to find as many "caches" as possible. The website typically caters locals, but that is what you/I want. You need a GPS unit. Any one suffice, but if you don't want to carry along all the papers with hidden caches, you might go for a subscription to geocaching.com and a more fancy GPS unit.

Having it as an app, can be specifically rewarding if you are traveling to a city, where a different language is spoken. You'll need google translate. The description might become a bit more complex to read after google translate, but coordinates don't need translations and even if you are not able to locate the cache, you are still directed to very interesting spot and google translate is often sufficient to get the main story.

Comment: I am looking for a person that knows a lot af a city to take my hand and show me the most important view of a city...